# How to check if image exists in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, filesystems

```
<%= image_tag("/images/users/user_" + @user_id.to_s + ".png") %>
```

How do you check to see if there is such an image, and if not, then display nothing?

Working in Rails 3.07.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [File.exist?](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_m_filetest.html).

```
if FileTest.exist?("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/images/#{img}")
  image_check = image_tag("#{img}",options)
else
  image_check = image_tag("products/noimg.gif", options)
end
```

Comment: What would be nice is to monkey patch image_tag that did this for you so you didn't have to repeat this for each image. So Check the file exists if it does, super. Otherwise super with noimg.gif. Or create your own helper image_or_default(img, options)

Comment: Yea I recommend doing the later because I hate modifying existing framework methods.

Comment: @BrianMaltzan then I would suggest using a db to know the path. This is what I do with large scale web applications that need a CDN.

Answer (score 11):

The other answers are a little outdated, due to changes in the Rails asset pipeline since Rails 4. The following code works in Rails 4 and 5:

If your file is placed in the **public** directory, then its existence can be checked with:

```
# File is stored in ./public/my_folder/picture.jpg
File.file? "#{Rails.public_path}/my_folder/picture.jpg"
```

However, if the file is placed in the **assets** directory then checking existence is a little harder, due to asset pre-compilation in production environments. I recommend the following approach:

```
# File is stored in ./app/assets/images/my_folder/picture.jpg

# The following helper could, for example, be placed in ./app/helpers/
def asset_exists?(path)
  if Rails.configuration.assets.compile
    Rails.application.precompiled_assets.include? path
  else
    Rails.application.assets_manifest.assets[path].present?
  end
end

asset_exists? 'my_folder/picture.jpg'
```

Comment: `Rails.application.assets_manifest.find_sources(path).present?`

Answer (score 9):

For **Rails 5** the one that worked for me is

`ActionController::Base.helpers.resolve_asset_path("logos/smthg.png")`

returns `nil` if the asset is absent and `path_of_the_asset` if present

Answer (score 3):

You can use File.file? method.

```
if File.file?("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/{image_name}")
  image_tag("#{image_name}")
end
```

You can also use File.exist? method but it will return true if it finds a directory or a file.
The method file? is slightly more picky than exist?