# Rails if image doesn't exist show text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to set my app up so on the user page, if they don't have any images, then it shows text saying that they don't. It will also show a link to upload new images.

I have tried this but it shows `undefined method 'image?' for #<WillPaginate::Collection:0x007f93a1e0e638>`

```
    - if @images.image?
        - @images.each do |image|
            = image_tag ("devices/#{image.device}.png"), :class => "img_#{image.device}"
            - if image.image?
                = link_to image_tag(image.image_url(:small), :class => "explore_#{image.device}"), image
            - else
                = image_tag '123-small.jpg', :class => "explore_#{image.device}"
    - else
        %p Looks like you don't have any images uploaded!
```

Edit: images_controller.rb

```
def index
   @title = "My Images"
   @images = current_user.images.paginate(:page => params[:page])
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if image exists in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969241/how-to-check-if-image-exists-in-rails)

Comment: show us corresponding controller code

Comment: Amir, it's not a duplicate as it is different.

Comment: Sergei, I will update the post with the controller code

Comment: I have changed `current_user.images.paginate(:page => params[:page])` to `current_user.images.all` and I am now getting `undefined method 'image?' for #<Array:0x007f939ea0b750>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to test whether there are any images in `@images`, and just using the wrong method for that. Instead try:

```
- if @images.present?
```

Comment: Brilliant. I was trying to use `.exists?`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, `@images` is obviously a `WillPaginate::Collection` of `image`, which acts like an array.

Therefore, to test whether `@images` is *not empty*, you should use `if @images.present?` or `unless @images.empty?` instead.