# check If images exists in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am adding images like this in rails project. I want to check If the image exists  and If not I want to use one common image for all the places where the images doesb't exist.

Please help.

```
          <div class = "col-sm-2"> 
         <center> 
          <%= image_tag pco.printable_photo.url(:small) %>
          <label>
            <%= pco.name %>
          </label>
        </center>
      </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if image exists in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969241/how-to-check-if-image-exists-in-rails)

Comment: thanks a lot for taking my attention there. I searched for js code earlier and hence couldn't land here on this

Comment: So this answer maybe help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9815854/3083093

Comment: so I Wanted it rails way , so below answer has helped me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a helper method in **application_helper.rb**:

```
def print_image(url)
  url = Rails.application.assets.find_asset(url).nil? ? nil : url
  image_tag url || 'default_image.jpg'
end
```

Then in your view, use this:

```
<%= print_image(pco.printable_photo.url(:small)) %>
```

Try to avoid writing logic in your view. Take the help of view helpers.

Comment: Try this, and let me what it prints, `print_image(pco.printable_photo.url(:small)).inspect`

Comment: It worked, I was doing it wrong way, thanks.. now what If I do not want to use helper, method, how do I do that then?

Comment: or can you explain me the 2nd line??

  url = Rails.application.assets.find_asset(url).nil? ? nil : url

Comment: @Suraj, I checked if the image file exists using `Rails.application.assets.find_asset(url).nil?`, this will return true if the image does not exists. Suppose you provided the url from database, but the file somehow has been deleted from filesystem, in that case this checking will help.

Comment: @Suraj, And if you don't want to write helper method, then you will have to write logic in your view, which is not a good practice.

Comment: @Suraj, if your problem is solved, don't forget to mark it as solved, then it will help others. Good luck. :)